# UE4. Возможность запрыгивать на объекты снизу

Tags: объекты, unreal-engine-4

Давненько рыскаю по интернету в поисках ответа на этот злосчастный вопрос. Обрисую картину кратко. Есть 2D игра, написанная на Unreal Engine 4. В ней персонаж, соответственно, тоже 2D. Помимо него есть объекты, на которые по сути можно запрыгнуть сверху. С этим никаких проблем нет. Просто добавить ему бокс и прыгай сколько хочешь. Но как сделать так, чтобы игрок мог проходить через этот бокс и умел становиться на него только тогда, когда он приземляется сверху. К примеру, это какая-то скамейка. Можно пройти мимо неё, а можно запрыгнуть сверху и встать на ней. Есть одна логика, мол если игрок падает и выше объекта по координатам, то включать бокс и давать возможность встать на объект, но это кажется сложноватым решением. Может есть что проще ? Оговорка: Прошу, не надо писать что UE больше подходит для 3D игр и тд. Я прекрасно это понимаю, и это никак не продвинет решение проблемы. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Здесь на юнити но возможно поможет написать по аналогии https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBVUUljDjS4

Comment: @grouptout, гляну, спасибо. Но там, как я понял сейчас, тот пример, о котором я говорил